# Flutter app icon does not change in ios simulator for flutter_launcher_icons

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator, appicon

I'ved used

flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4 - https://alligator.io/flutter/app-icons/

and ran the command in my mac.

After relaunching the app, I noticed the app icon is not changed.

But if opened in xcode and deploy to device/appstore, the app icon is updated.

Why is IOS simulator not showing the updated app icon ?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the icon mapping using XCode. It could be something wrong in the file `Contents.json`. To investigate more :

1. Open your workspace on the `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` or the project `ios/Runner.xcodeproj`.
2. In the XCode open `Runner/Assets.xcassets` and you will find something [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYZqA.png).
3. Check the warning (if it appeared). To fix the mapping issue check also file in `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/Contents.json` from your flutter project base folder and see if the mapping correct.
4. Don't forget to reset the cache of the simulator so the new icon also appears in the task menu.